# Replacing a string that appears as '??'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to replace '??' in the following string:
'Martin ??degaard'
the ?? should be an Ø but I am trying to replace it with just an O.

The string is located in a dataframe and I have attempted this using the following code:

```
df = df.replace('??', 'O', regex=True)
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what is `df`?  A dataframe where every column in a Series of strings?

Comment: `?` is a special character in regular expressions. Try escaping it: `df.replace(r'\?{2}', 'O', regex=True)`

Comment: "Dataframe.replace" expects a regular expression where the question mark has a special meaning. Replace `'??'` by `r'\?\?'`

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a special character in RegEx and needs to be escaped. The RegEx to match `??` literally is `\?\?`.

The issue is reproducible without `pandas` just using the `re` module, so ideally your MRE should not have used pandas. Here is the working code just with `re`, which will work by extension for your dataframe:

```
import re
str_ = 'Martin ??degaard'
print(re.sub('\?\?', 'O', str_))
```

Output:

```
Martin Odegaard
```

So use:

```
df = df.replace('\?\?', 'O', regex=True)
```